# Powershell Get cmdlet with special characters

Tags: powershell, cluster-computing, special-characters, powershell-cmdlet

I'm trying to get some cluster ressource informaiton with powershell Get-ClusterResource cmdlet.

When querying all data I get everything good like this.

**Spouleur d'impression Online cimpadm01 Print Spooler**

But when I'm trying to query a specific resource that has an " ' " in, it  fails!

```
Get-ClusterResource -name "Spouleur d'impression"
*Get-ClusterResource : Une erreur s'est produite lors de l'ouverture de la ressource « Spouleur d'impression ».*
```

When I try the same query with another resource it works

```
Get-ClusterResource -name "Disque du cluster 1"

Disque du cluster 1   Online   cimpadm01   Physical Disk
```

I tried so far

- escaping with "`"
- using multiple double and single quote
- tried with a variable
- tried with piping a where object

I'm out of ideas!

Thanks

Comment: i don't know what the fix is ... but i have run into this sort of thing so often that i _do not_ put such in names. no punctuation, no spaces, no characters other than the printable basic ascii ones.

Comment: Tried with the "*" but not luck.
The name was given by windows, the os is in french :(

Comment: What happened when you tried `Where-Object`? Does this return anything: `Get-ClusterResource | ?{$_.Name -like "Spouleur d*impression"}`  ?

Comment: Thanks rRich!!! That was the way to go!!! This return the correct value.
`powershell -nologo -command "Import-Module failoverclusters ;  Get-ClusterResource | ?{$_.Name -like 'Spouleur d*impression ('}|foreach {$_.State}"`
I'm getting the state online!
I'm gonna edit my script so it will replace the " ' " by " * ".
Thanks again!

Comment: Turns out addind another  "," fix the command :
 `powershell -nologo -command "Import-Module failoverclusters ;  $test='Spouleur d''impression';Get-ClusterResource | ?{$_.Name -like $test.replace('''','*')}|foreach {$_.State}"`